# Powershell Search search 2 column csv and return matches concatenated

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, search, text

Here is my dilemma.  I have a csv file with two columns

```
ID,FullFileName  
1,Value1  
1,Value2  
1,Value3  
2,Value1  
2,Value2  
3,Value1  
4,Value1  
5,Value1  
5,Value2
```

The output I'm looking for is to get an exported csv with two columns in it  ID, and FullFilename.  The value in FullFileName will contain the matching joined values separated by a pipe delimiter.

But my output i'm trying to get the following:

```
ID,FullFilename  
1,Value1|Value2|Value3  
2,Value1|Value2  
3,Value1  
4,Value1  
5,Value1|Value2
```

I'm not sure how to make powershell search the value in ID and take all of the results and yield them into a single concatenated value with a pipe separation.  Any assistance on trying to search the array or join / concatenate array values would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group-Object is the useful cmdlet that can help you. Grouping the data by ID turns it into:

```
PS D:\> ipcsv .\t.csv | group id

Count Name Group
----- ---- -----
    3 1    {@{ID=1; FullFileName=Value1}, @{ID=1; FullFileName=Value2}, @{ID=1; FullFileName=Value3}}
    2 2    {@{ID=2; FullFileName=Value1}, @{ID=2; FullFileName=Value2}}
    1 3    {@{ID=3; FullFileName=Value1}}
    1 4    {@{ID=4; FullFileName=Value1}}
    2 5    {@{ID=5; FullFileName=Value1}, @{ID=5; FullFileName=Value2}}
```

So you want the Name (= ID) and the Group property, just the FullFileName, joined up:

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\path\data.csv | 
    Group-Object -Property ID | 
    Select-Object @{Name='ID'; Expression={$_.Name}},
                  @{Name='FullFilename'; Expression={$_.Group.FullFileName -join '|'}} | 
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Path\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$InFile = '.\Sample.csv'
$OutFile= '.\New.csv'
$Csv = Import-Csv $InFile | Group-Object ID | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ID=$_.Name
        FullFileName=$_.Group.FullFileName -join '|'
    }
} 
$Csv
"----------"
$Csv | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
Get-Content $OutFile
```

Sample output:

```
ID FullFileName
-- ------------
1  Value1|Value2|Value3
2  Value1|Value2
3  Value1
4  Value1
5  Value1|Value2
----------
"ID","FullFileName"
"1","Value1|Value2|Value3"
"2","Value1|Value2"
"3","Value1"
"4","Value1"
"5","Value1|Value2"
```

**Edit** Just saw you wanted the pipe as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Did my best but was to late, anyway here is the code

Instead of Group-Object i am using a HashTable, i find it easy to work with when my data comes from multiple sources.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Path "$env:TEMP\testfolder\csv.txt" #can be .csv or whatever.
$HastTable = @{}

Foreach ($Line in $CSV) {
    if (!$HastTable["$($Line.ID)"]) {
        $HastTable["$($Line.ID)"] = $Line
    } 

    else {
        $HastTable["$($Line.ID)"].FullFileName += "|$($Line.FullFileName)"
    }
}

$HastTable.Values | Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation -Path "$env:TEMP\testfolder\newcsv.txt" #can be .csv or whatever.
```